# Appcelerator / Titanium - Countdown on hold with animation?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I would like to create a fancy "hold refresh" where a bubble grows in size until for example 3 seconds has passed.

When the 3 seconds has passed the user can release the fingerpress and the page will refresh.

Now, I have the code to perform many of these things, but Im struggeling with the timer and size.

```
// HOLD REFRESH
        var holdTime = 2000, timeout, startTime = 0, timer = 0, timerOk = false;
        var overLay = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor: '#D9266BAF',
            zIndex: '50',
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        });
        var overLayText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text: 'Hold to update content..',
            color: 'white',
        });
        var overLayImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image: '/images/pullRefresh_white.png',
            height: '30',
            bottom: '40'
        });
        overLay.add(overLayText);

        TileData.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){

            TileData.add(overLay);

            timeout = setTimeout(function(e){
                timerOk = true;
                overLayText.text = 'Release to update content';
                overLay.add(overLayImage);
            }, holdTime);

        });

        TileData.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timer = 0;
            TileData.remove(overLay);
            overLay.remove(overLayImage);
            overLayText.text = 'Hold to update content..';
        });

        TileData.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timer = 0;
            if(timerOk){

                MainController.openView('dashboard');
            }else{
                TileData.remove(overLay);
                overLay.remove(overLayImage);
                overLayText.text = 'Hold to update content..';
            }
        });
        //
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not exactly clear. I think I understand what you want achieve and you may achieve it in a few ways:

1. Inside `touchstart` event create animation of duration same as your holdtime. Set proper values for height/width and Appcelerator will manage scaling for you. In `startend` event clear that animation. You may also use `animationcomplete` event for calling refresh function.
2. During `touchstart`, `touchend` event set true/false value for variable `ifClicked` and using small intervals/timeouts (it is better to use `setInterval` function than `setTimeout`) check if user still touch it. Within those interval u can also do small steps of animation.